# Is there empirical evidence supporting a universe expanding faster than light?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, faster-than-light, cosmological-inflation

We receive no light from galaxies beyond the cosmological horizon, but if they were moving away only at light speed, it seems to me their light wouldn't reach us.  Is there any observations or empirical evidence that shows or implies they are moving away from us faster than light?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60519/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/251412/123208

Answer (score -3, accepted):

No, if the universe is in hyperspace, then that means that it can go infinitely fast, but in the actual universe, the speed limit is the speed of light and nothing can get to there except light.

Comment: If there is anything wrong with the answer, please let me know so I can improve it. Thanks

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but what is your definition of "hyperspace" and what would the consequences of travelling "infinitely" fast be? Regds

Comment: Hyperspace, would be somewhere that is not bound by the laws of space-time and would technically be another dimension. This would mean that you could go faster than the speed of light. What I mean by infinitely fast is that you would be able to accelerate and keep accelerating as you would not be bound by the laws of physics. This really would not have any consequences as for objects inside our universe because these (theoretically) are two different dimensions and one is in another.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the universe is decelerating, light emitted from sources beyond the Hubble sphere will eventually reach us.  See this post for a detailed answer: [If the expansion of the universe slowed what would we observe?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/400046/if-the-expansion-of-the-universe-slowed-what-would-we-observe/400090#400090)